Scala - List("a","b").map(fn) versus map(fn, List("a","b")
From Scala's site, there is an example of reimplementing method map for List, and the usage of it is as below
Case 1
def strlen(s: String): Int = s.length
map(strlen, List("a", "bb", "ccc"))   // List(1, 2, 3)

From native support of scala, calling map on List would be as below:
Case 1
List("a","b").map(x => x.length)

How to write map that could be called like the native way?
Specifically, I want to clarify about this: within the example of scala (Case 1), the implementation utilize Functor. But, from source code on github of scala, the implemention does not utilize Functor.

Did you tried to look at map source code?

@talex I have just updated the question to clarify that I would like to ask is about using Functor. In the git repo of scala, I don't realize the usage of Functor in the implemtation.

You need to use an extension method and change the name or be in a context where the compiler doesn't know the type is List

To expand on @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: extension methods are used only when compiler cannot prove that the type already has method of that name. It happens either when it actually do not have it, or when the compiler see the abstract type, e.g. type parameter/generic type (inside parametric method/class the horizon for the compiler is what was defined in the upper type bound) and someone applied the type there. If an extension method is available for such case, it will be used (either because it was defined on the upper bound or because extension used implicit that was passed for abstract type).

Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, Mateusz Kubuszok: Your suggestion provides one more aspect that I have not yet learnt.

You can look into type classes. Check the example for Show type class, representing "anything that can be shown". It's the same in your case, except you want "anything that can be mapped". You would then implement a type class instance for your desired type (in your example List) and provide it using the implicit/given mechanism (depending on Scala 2 vs Scala 3).
Functor is a functional programming construct coming from category theory, and in simple and concrete terms, it's exactly that - a representation of "something that can be mapped". It is usually found in functional programming Scala libraries such as Cats, Zio, ex-twitter's Algebrid etc, and it is implemented via described type class mechanism. There are many kinds of collections that can implement the Functor type class - most collections (such as List), but also e.g. Option, even effect types such as Future / IO / Task etc.
However, native Scala doesn't use the Functor approach; it simply implements map directly in the collections hierarchy, which in case of List would be in Traversable (iirc).
Of course, it doesn't make sense to add (another) map to a List, but I'm assuming you're asking for learning purposes. You could practice by adding another map-like method to List (e.g. myMap). In that case you can define your own type class (e.g. Mappable) and provide an instance/implementation of that type class for List. Another interesting practice would be to define a custom collection (e.g. MyList) and write a Functor instance for it, so that you can do myList.map(someFunction).

Please clarify more detail about: A representation of "something that can be mapped". This example:
case class Bag[A](content: A) {def map[B](f: A => B): Bag[B] = Bag(f(content))} ;
trait Functor[F[_]] {def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]} ;
case object bagFunctorVersion2 extends Functor[Bag] {def map[A,B](as: Bag[A])(f: A=> B): Bag[B] = as.map(f)} ; The implementation (i.e: bagFunctorVersion2) using Functor would then call function ".map" of type Bag. But logic of ".map" of Bag already done what Functor provides. Which scenario that Functor would provide more than ".map" can provide?

I have just realized/understood that, the example provides Bag which is already a Functor. To this point, I wonder how many way in Scala that we can implement a Functor? And how can the logic of bagFunctorVersion2  could go beyond the logic that Bag's map has provided?

Those are all great questions. "I wonder how many way in Scala that we can implement a Functor" - most of the time just one, but sometimes there is a choice. For example, you could implement a map on a Tuple[A, B] as acting on the left side, or the right side (we call that left-biased and right-biased). "Which scenario that Functor would provide" - you would be able to write highly generic code, for example a function that takes an argument of "any type A, as long as Functor[A] exists". Remember also that FP libraries bring Functor instances for many existing types, not just List.

Also, when implementing map for some Functor instance, there is a set of mathematical laws that need to be obeyed. So if you would use some FP library and want to provide an instance of Functor[MyType] for some custom MyType, you would have to make sure that your implementation respects those laws. Two functor laws are identity and associativity, you can look them up. First can be written as m.map(x => x) == m, second as m.map(f).map(g) == m.map(x => g(f(x)).

That helps a lot.  Can you help to give an example of GENERIC that simple enough to the example of Bag above. Please clarify: I'm aware that Functor must satisfy some rules regarding to Category theory. Assume that we can put aside those rules (i.e skip those rules for now), then, a Functor like bagFunctorVersion2  above would eventually trigger Bag's map. I mean, "something that can be mapped" already has a function "map", why would we need to create a Functor and let that Functor trigger ".map" of such thing?

You would not. Main usage of type classes (including things like Functor) is to allow you to write generic code, using a kind of polymorphism that's a bit more flexible than other common solutions (such as inheritance). You can read more about that in a blogpost I wrote a while ago. Typical example: with inheritance, you can't force an existing Duck (not your code) to inherit/extend CanSwim, but with type classes, you can implement a CanSwim[Duck].

So what happens in the real world is usually:

You don't have (and don't need) anything like bagFunctorVersion2. You just use existing functors and their map. And you can write a function that doesn't take "a List" or "an Option", but simply "something that has a functor" (which is already defined for List, Option etc, and you can provide your own functor implementations for your own types)
You are writing a completely new type class with its own methods. Then you can write some implementations for existing common types, and let others also implement it for their own types.


"something that can be mapped already has a function map, why would we need to create a Functor and let that Functor trigger .map of such thing?" - This shows your confusion so let me just reiterate what I wrote above. You would not "create a functor". Functional programming (FP) libraries already come packed with such type classes, see here. You would simply use them, by writing code such as "something that has a Functor and has a Monoid" or whatever. And totally unrelated to that, you can implement your own type classes.

Ii'm using Scala 2.12.4 for the example from your blog post. The definition of second one: toAppendable(s: String); would override the definition of toAppendable(i: Int); so that when I triggered this one: val res1 = appendItems(2, 3), it returns an error like this: :15: error: No implicit view available from Int => Appendable[Int]. In addition to that, I'm aware that all Scala functions are instance of Functor, but explicitly, please clarify what is the functor from your 1st and 2nd runnable examples in the blog?

With the 2nd example, in which we have object Appendable { implicit val appendableInt ...  implicit val appendableString ... } ; it also returns error respectively for these 2 statements: val res1 = appendItems(2, 3) ; :12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Appendable[Int] ; also;  val res2 = appendItems("2", "3") ; :12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Appendable[String]; Please share which version of Scala that works for you with these examples. Thank you.
